# How can you access javascript variables from a C#.Net Webbrowser object?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I want to create a Webbrowser .Net object from my C#.Net Winform application and then be able to access javascript variables.

Basically I want to take some action in my main Winform application depending on some user interactions that happen that set javascript variables.

Any advice on how I can make calls to the Webbrowser object to do this?

Note I did look at the Document property that lets you get at the DOM but don't understand how/if that can be used to get at javascript variables.

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the WinForms browser, use the [`ObjectForScripting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to handle two-way communications between your WinForms application and your `WebBrowser`'s `Document`.

You can invoke javascript members from C# through the `Document` object:

```
 // C# code
 webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("test",
        new String[] { "called from client code" });
```

Assigning `ObjectForScripting` as

```
// C# code
webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = obj;
```

appears to allow the hosted javascript to call members of `obj`, e.g.

```
// javascript code
window.external.SomeMethod('called from script code');
// executes obj.SomeMethod(string) in C#
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I only have experience with the WPF web browser, so I haven't verified the above myself.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [CeSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Getting-Started), a Chromium Embedded Framework that allows much more control over your webbrowser component.

**To get started**

- Fire up a VS project
- Open nuget console and execute: `Install-Package CefSharp.WinForms` if you are doing Winforms C# App.
- Restart your Visual studio and re-load project.

**Example of CefSharp code to get started.**

- Add a toolStripContainer to your form from the toolbox then use the following example code to load cefsharp browser component.

  public Form1()
  {
        InitializeComponent();
        var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost:1071/");

  ```
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(browser);
  ```

  }

This should get you started, in order to talk to JS from C# you will need to make use of `EvaluateScript` interface.

Take a look at the following resource.
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/368